# Magento grid filter index for custom column

Tags: magento, grid, renderer

In **Magento Grid**

a) While preparing collection I did some calculations in query and got those values as extra column-

`ex - select 1 as extracolumn`

Now how can I set `filter_index` and sorting on this column

### OR

b) I am using rendering to show custom data in a column, How can I set `filter_index` and sorting on this column

Answer (score 2):

I tried the suggestion from shadowice222 but it didn't allow me to filter on the field. Looked at the core code and it complains about the 'my_column' not being defined. Using the addExpressionAttributeToSelect does the same as thing internally but also adds the column.

The empty array is to bypass the code which does the variable replacement as that would try to cast the Zend_Db_Expr to a string. Perhaps a better approach would be to extend the class to have an addZendDbExptToSelect method.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    ...
    $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('my_column', new Zend_Db_Expr("(some expression)"), array());
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected function _getFlatExpressionColumn($key) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'my_column':
            $result = new Zend_Db_Expr("(some expression)");
            break;
    }
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    ...
    $col->getSelect()
        ->columns(array(
            'my_column' => $this->_getFlatExpressionColumn('my_column'),
        ))
    ;
    ...
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    ...
    $this->addColumn('my_column', array(
        'header'        => $hlp->__('My Column Title'),
        'index'         => 'my_column',
        'filter_index'  => $this->_getFlatExpressionColumn('my_column'),
    ));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

show how can work this function :

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_addColumnFilterToCollection
```

Is here you can make your filter for the renderers data

Comment: lets take an example- 
 protected function _prepareCollection()
   {
       $collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')->getCollection(); //this table doesnt have status column so I am using renderer
  $this->setCollection($collection);
       return parent::_prepareCollection();
   }
 
 $this->addColumn('status', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('module')->__('Object'),
      'filter_index'    => ????,
   'renderer' => new Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Status(),
  
  ));
What filter_index should be used and how _addColumnFilterToCollection method shld be overridden